# For each activity in azure synapse

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

A notebook needs to be run over a set of Array of arrays in for each activity . Is there a way to pass in that subarray as a parameter to the notebook that's inside for each activity.

The datatype for a parameter in notebook in synapse doesn't accept an array type

Answer (score 0):

Currently, Notebook activity does not support passing arrays to Notebook.

So, pass it as String, then In Notebook convert it into array.

**My Array parameter in pipeline:**

[image]

Inside ForEach, pass it as String.

[image]

**Output of Notebook in one iteration:**

Use `eval()` to convert string in to list in Notebook.

[image]